# Forced to stay only mine app and can not open another app

Tags: android

I am developing one android application. In that i need to do below task. Can anyone suggest me how to do below task?

> I want to force to user to stay on mine app, he/she can not open
>   another app. Only mine app is visible to top?

How can i achieve this?

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: you can make a launcher app. Once in it, the only way out is the recent apps button, and if you start another app. (and, the notification on the lock screen, and the incoming call screen)

Comment: Only if you create your custom rom

Comment: only if you have control of the actually devices, you could set up user accounts and restrict the apps that the user can open

Comment: I don't think you can do it if you are not having your own modified ROM because it's not permissible in the regular OS. Though +1 for the question but need to post more R&D conclusion you have got so other can start from there and can do more help. +1 to you too @user1940676

Answer (score 1):

I had a requirement where I need my App to run in foreground always, so that no other App should be running other than my App. Also, I had created a menu inside my App to Exit the Service that I created that keeps my App running always in foreground (not in this demo).

I had created a demo for the same in my github named as [MyBackgroundServiceDemo](https://github.com/lalit3686/MyBackgroundServiceDemo).

**Notes:**

1. My requirement was for Tablet only.
2. I disabled back button of my App.
3. When user presses home button it will stay to home for 5 seconds (which is default by Android).
4. My Service keeps running constantly to keep track of Apps that are running.

I had modified the Service according to my requirement later on to keep track of my requirements. Same way you also modify the Service to meet your requirement.